# Convert hexadecimal string (hex) to a binary string

Tags: java, binary, hex

I found the following way hex to binary conversion:

```
String binAddr = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(hexAddr, 16));
```

While this approach works for small hex numbers, a hex number such as the following

```
A14AA1DBDB818F9759
```

Throws a `NumberFormatException.`

I therefore wrote the following method that seems to work:

```
private String hexToBin(String hex){
    String bin = "";
    String binFragment = "";
    int iHex;
    hex = hex.trim();
    hex = hex.replaceFirst("0x", "");

    for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++){
        iHex = Integer.parseInt(""+hex.charAt(i),16);
        binFragment = Integer.toBinaryString(iHex);

        while(binFragment.length() < 4){
            binFragment = "0" + binFragment;
        }
        bin += binFragment;
    }
    return bin;
}
```

The above method basically takes each character in the Hex string and converts it to its binary equivalent pads it with zeros if necessary then joins it to the return value. 
Is this a proper way of performing a conversion? Or am I overlooking something that may cause my approach to fail?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Would a long not work for what you are wanting?  It also has the ToBinaryString(). That would support...

Ranges from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: if that does what you'd like let me know so I can post as the answer please.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. You may also look at following link: http://java2everyone.blogspot.in/2009/04/java-hexadecimal-to-binary.html?m=1

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[`BigInteger.toString(radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) will do what you want.  Just pass in a radix of 2.

```
static String hexToBin(String s) {
  return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: Indeed.  The only issue here is that the numbers grow too big to fit in an `int`.

Comment: That's the point, sorry.  Overflow is the problem with the OP's code, and this solution fixes it.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was missing.

Comment: Unfortunately, toString(2) doesn't pad with zeroes

Comment: @AndreyBotalov, quite right.  That the OP's code produces 4 bits per hex digit seemed incidental to me, so I assumed no padding was required.

Comment: This is an old question but how to pad with zeroes?

Comment: For a width of 8 bits: `String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(s)).replace(' ', '0');`

Comment: Thanks it helped me so much

Answer (score 13):

Fast, and works for large strings:

```
    private String hexToBin(String hex){
        hex = hex.replaceAll("0", "0000");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("1", "0001");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("2", "0010");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("3", "0011");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("4", "0100");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("5", "0101");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("6", "0110");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("7", "0111");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("8", "1000");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("9", "1001");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("A", "1010");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("B", "1011");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("C", "1100");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("D", "1101");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("E", "1110");
        hex = hex.replaceAll("F", "1111");
        return hex;
    }
```

Comment: Works good, keeps leading 0s as well.

Comment: This is the only solution that keeps all leading and trailing zero's the rest doesn't.

Comment: thank you so much. only one solution work prefectly

Answer (score 6):

```
Integer.parseInt(hex,16);    
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(hex));
```

Parse hex(String) to integer with base 16 then convert it to Binary String using toBinaryString(int) method

example

```
int num = (Integer.parseInt("A2B", 16));
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(num));
```

Will Print

```
101000101011
```

Max Hex vakue Handled by int is FFFFFFF

i.e. if FFFFFFF0 is passed ti will give error

Answer (score 2):

With all zeroes:

```
static String hexToBin(String s) {
    String preBin = new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
    Integer length = preBin.length();
    if (length < 8) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8 - length; i++) {
            preBin = "0" + preBin;
        }
    }
    return preBin;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static byte[] hexToBin(String str)
    {
        int len = str.length();
        byte[] out = new byte[len / 2];
        int endIndx;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i = i + 2)
        {
            endIndx = i + 2;
            if (endIndx > len)
                endIndx = len - 1;
            out[i / 2] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, endIndx), 16);
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class HexadeciamlToBinary
{
   public static void main()
   {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("enter the hexadecimal number");
       String s=sc.nextLine();
       String p="";
       long n=0;
       int c=0;
       for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
       {
          if(s.charAt(i)=='A')
          {
             n=n+(long)(Math.pow(16,c)*10);
             c++;
          }
         else if(s.charAt(i)=='B')
         {
            n=n+(long)(Math.pow(16,c)*11);
            c++;
         }
        else if(s.charAt(i)=='C')
        {
            n=n+(long)(Math.pow(16,c)*12);
            c++;
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i)=='D')
        {
           n=n+(long)(Math.pow(16,c)*13);
           c++;
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i)=='E')
        {
            n=n+(long)(Math.pow(16,c)*14);
            c++;
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i)=='F')
        {
            n=n+(long)(Math.pow(16,c)*15);
            c++;
        }
        else
        {
            n=n+(long)Math.pow(16,c)*(long)s.charAt(i);
            c++;
        }
    }
    String s1="",k="";
    if(n>1)
    {
    while(n>0)
    {
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            k=k+"0";
            n=n/2;
        }
        else
        {
            k=k+"1";
            n=n/2;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k.length();i++)
    {
        s1=k.charAt(i)+s1;
    }
    System.out.println("The respective binary number is : "+s1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The respective binary number is : "+n);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static byte[] hexToBytes(String string) {
 int length = string.length();
 byte[] data = new byte[length / 2];
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
  data[i / 2] = (byte)((Character.digit(string.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(string.charAt(i + 1), 16));
 }
 return data;
}
```