# Why is there an extra block when encrypting?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

I am passing input data 20 bytes long and java AES-CBC returns 48 bytes instead of 32 which is what I think it should output because of padding. My key is 16 bytes long.

```
byte[] ciphertext;
byte[] thekey = new byte[16];
new Random().nextBytes(thekey);
byte[] vector = new byte[16];
new Random().nextBytes(vector);
String s = "c6be25d903159d680d81f3d99bb702451e9f7158";
byte[] data = s.getBytes();
Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");           
enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(thekey, "AES"), 
        new IvParameterSpec(vector));
ciphertext = enc.doFinal(data);


/* Sample Output*/
StringBuffer testvec = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer test = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer testkey = new StringBuffer();
for (byte b:vector){
testvec.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                                }
System.out.println("Vector:"  + " " +testvec.toString());
for (byte b:ciphertext){
test.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                                }

System.out.println(" Cipher:"+ " " + test.toString());


for (byte b:thekey){
testkey.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                                }

System.out.println("theKey:"+ " " + testkey.toString());
```

Sample output:

Vector: c6ab4c2b0b220b8b3520bd20e3741a1e

Cipher: **3dd2cb1f94c99940fd4f7d1a503a091844dc16c8bae480d748453859701b72fecd949e158d2103ba99560d64ee65f6cb**

theKey: bc03f2e674a0d482d0c6677d211eb14e

Comment: If you can't be bothered to copy & paste compilable code then we can't be bothered to answer your questions. There is no getbytes method of the String class.

Comment: getBytes() not getbytes()

Comment: @dfs Your code still won't compile. Please create a MSCE, i.e. code we can run as snippet without compile errors.

Comment: In particular there is no `.getBytes()` method on `data` which is `byte[]`. The only methods on any array type are those of `java.lang.Object`. If you are actually encrypting `data`, then it is 40 bytes and encrypting 40 bytes with padding in a 128-bit block cipher like AES is correctly 48 bytes.

Comment: added full working code with sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code as such, and am unable to reproduce your result.  My input is 20 bytes, as 20 characters of the alphabet, and output is 32 bytes as expected.  I put Logs verifying both the input before encryption size and the output.

Try putting logs in as I did and verifying the input/output as here.

```
    try {

         byte[] inputBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrst".getBytes("UTF-8");

         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");   
         SecretKey sk = getCastedActivity().getSecretKey();

         SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sk.getEncoded(), "AES");

         //Confirmed 20 bytes input 
         Log.i(TAG, "InputBytes length " + inputBytes.length);

         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(MyEncrypt.generateIv()));
         byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

         //As expected 32 byte encrypted size.
         Log.i(TAG, "OutputBytes length " + encryptedBytes.length);

     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "encryption exception", e);
     }
```

Comment: Your input is 40 bytes, not 20.  Your output is 48 bytes, not 96 bytes.  You are running stuff through a formatter .02x that is turning bytes into 2 digit characters, hence you appear to be double counting.  The numbers match what is expected.

Comment: "<SomeHexString>".getBytes() is not how to convert hexadecimal back to the original binary.  When you convert bytes to hexadecimal each byte becomes 2 characters, and when you call getBytes() each character becomes one byte, so you doubled your original number of bytes...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hexadecimal-string-hex-to-a-binary-string

Comment: I did not actually convert the string representing a hexadecimal number to an actual hex number. What a stupid mistake. Thanks!