# How to convert Hex String to binary string with leading zeros?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a hex String as `0F0A`. I need the output as `0000111100001010`. I tried the following method but this returns `111100001010` - I need the leading `0000` as well.

```
public static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
    return new BigInteger(hex, 16).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: You must refer this question, I hope this will definately help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hexadecimal-string-hex-to-a-binary-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hexadecimal-string-hex-to-a-binary-string) This might help.

Answer (score 3):

you are almost there... just need to format it:

```
   String string = "0f0a";
   String value = new BigInteger(string, 16).toString(2);
   String formatPad = "%" + (string.length() * 4) + "s";
   System.out.println(String.format(formatPad, value).replace(" ", "0"));
```

the formatPad is the padder (4 bit for each hex symbol)... in your case **16**

Comment: And what if he doesn't know beforehand how long his input string is?

Comment: OK, thanks for demonstrating it.  I don't think beginners always realize they can compute a format string.  I strongly suggest you put `string.length() * 4` in parentheses.  Since the `+` is string concatenation and `*` is arithmetic multiplication, you really shouldn't combine the two types in the same expression without parentheses; I've seen things like `String1 + number + 1` or `String1 + number - 1` too often, which doesn't work.  Yours will work due to operator precedence, but it's a bit confusing without the parens.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
String hexToBinary(String hexString) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    String padded = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0') 
    return padded;
}
```

Comment: And if his input is too large to fit in an `Integer`?  The OP didn't say anything about how long his input string could be.  And your code will not give him the output he wants on the input he specified--did you try it?