# convert hex file into binary file

Tags: java, android, hex

How to convert hex file into binary file. I want code in core Java. to convert hex file into binary file which would be taken by user from dialogue in android application.
Thanks

Comment: stop `I want`, `I want` and try out something

Comment: I don't know what a hex file is. Any file can be read as a binary file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
String hexToBinary(String hex) {
int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
return bin;
}
```

otherwise check this link
 : [Convert hexadecimal string (hex) to a binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hexadecimal-string-hex-to-a-binary-string)

Comment: Thanks @damini Mehra